# Log in and collect data from extranet page using CURL and cookies

Tags: php, curl, single-sign-on, sap-basis

I am writing a script which will log in to a SAP extranet page using cookie and grab some cookies using CURL (I need to collect data about prices of products on this page). My code looks like this:

```
//username and password of accounts
//trim-remove whitespaces from strings

$username = trim("John");
$password = trim("123");

//set the directory for the cookie using defined document root var
$dir = DOC_ROOT."/ctemp";
//build a unique path with every request to store
//the info per user with custom func.
$path = build_unique_path($dir);

//login form action url
$url="http://destination.com";
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);
```

I get an error at URL "`https://api.skype.com/detection/detection_as3.swf`" (it's an example):

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

It connects to the server but doesn't collect cookies properly/entirely, I receive: active, sap-usercontext, sap-appcontext,  sap-hostid and MYSAPSSO2, which is not what I need.

Does anyone have an idea why this code doesn't work?

I tried to change curl_setopt parameters but it didn't worked. I also looked for similar questions or examples but I haven't found anything helplful

Comment: When i look at the page, it does not exist. Could it be that the page you try to reach does not exist ?

Comment: i changed the url, it's just an example